# How have an endpoint that accepts both JSON and CSV?

Tags: json, spring, rest

So my API currently accepts requests, and responses in `application/json`

Say I have the following endpoint for bulk user creation:

```
POST /users/bulk
{
  "users": [
    {
      "name": "Roger Wilco",
      "email": "roge@example.org",
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Now I want it to be able to create users by uploading a CSV.

I've seen the spring guide for uploading files:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/

Assuming that the (new) endpoint will be called both directly, and also through html submissions, which content-types should I be handling in the controller?

Comment: If you can, yes. As for what to handle in the controller - that would be an object or a hashmap. I am not too familiar with Spring, but if made from ground up, I would "prepare" the request abstraction, before it is handed of to the controller. Your controllers are not deciding how to handle `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `multipart/form-data` in a standard web project .. so .. why would they care about `application/json` vs `text/csv`

Comment: @tereško what about the second question? :)